# Set jQuery.ajax then execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Let's say I want to create a var:

```
var ajax = $.ajax( url )
            .done( function (response) {
                //done body
            })
            .fail( function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
                //fail
            })
            .always( function () {
                //always
            });
```

But I don't want it to send request immediately. I want to do something like:

```
ajax.execute();
```

At some point further, or perhaps just unsetting it. Is that possible?

The key in this question is to use full functionality of jQuery's ajax without wrapper, or with a wrapper that can use all current $.ajax methods + potentially new without adding code.

Comment: You can write your own method, but I do not think jQuery has anything like that built in.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function and then use jQuery to listen for an event to trigger the function.  E.G.

```
$("button").on("click", function(event) {
  fireAjax();
});

function fireAjax() {
    ....do call here
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not a function?

```
var ajax = function ajax(url, doneFunc, failFunc, alwaysFunc){

    var functions = {
        "done":doneFunc,
        "fail":failFunc,
        "always":alwaysFunc
    };

    this.execute = function(){
        $.ajax( url )
            .done(functions.done)
            .fail(functions.fail)
            .always(functions.always);
    };

}
```

Comment: Of course function is a solution, but in that case I will need to specify done, fail etc as args like `var ajax = function ajax(url, done, fail)`, but I want them to be optional.

Comment: If they don't exist, replace by a default function or an empty one.

Comment: @Filipe You don't really need it, jQuery should already handles undefined callback. EDIT: [see](http://jsfiddle.net/hnk4zymq/) EDIT2: oops, i guess you mean passing e.g `null` as callback

Comment: The key in this question is to use full functionality of jQuery's ajax without wrapper, or with a wrapper that can use all current $.ajax methods + potentially new without adding code.

Comment: @abr So it was unclear question... You are more looking for extending `$.ajax` method instead

Comment: Hmmm. That changes things.

Comment: @Filipe You'd have better to edit your question to make it more clear because judging by all different answers you get, it is really unclear what you are expecting...

Answer (score 0):

You could use XMLHttpRequest directly

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();        
oReq.open("GET", url);
oReq.send();
```

[Mozilla specs for XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.ajaxSetup()` to define options that should be used, or could be overwritten

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  url: "",
  success: success,
  error: error
});
```

Calling `$.ajax()` here would use `url` , `success` function , `error` function defined at `$.ajaxSetup()`. Alternatively, if `settings` should be changed, pass settings that should be changed at `$.ajax()` call; e.g.; `$.ajax({url:"abc"}).always(fn)` would still use `success` , `error` functions defined, though new `url` set.